# Нужно ли логировать собственные библиотеки

Tags: логирование

Предположим, я разрабатываю библиотеку или просто некоторый модуль для своей программы, нужно ли мне ее/его логгировать?

Склоняюсь к тому, что нужно только выбрасывать исключения или коды ошибок, по причинам:

1. Если я буду логировать методы своего класса, то, при выбросе исключения в методе, он будет прологирован как в методе класса, так и в модуле, который его вызвал, то есть будет двойное логирование, а если таких уровней будет больше чем два?
2. Чужие библиотеки в продакшене не логируются

С другой стороны, логирование своих библиотек позволит мне иметь полный контроль над всем ходом выполнения программы

Прихожу к выводу, что нужно логировать свои библиотеки только на этапе тестирования.
Но тогда мне придется на самом верхнем уровне помещать в try вызов каждой функции/метода, которое может выкинуть исключение, чтобы иметь полноту информации, что не очень удобно

Не подскажете, как мне действовать?

Comment: Логировать проблемы должен конечный пользователь приложения. А библиотеки должны просто выбрасывать внятные человекочитаемые исключения

Comment: *"нужно логировать свои библиотеки только на этапе отладки"* --- для отладки, во-первых, существует сама...эммм....отладка..... а во-вторых - тестирование

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, хорошо, на этапе тестирования, оговорился, с кем не бывает?

Comment: На этапе тестирования применяют...эмм...тестирование...))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, смысл тестирования, если я не могу узнать, что происходит во время него? Просто потыкать кнопочки?)

Comment: В Java-мире библиотеки сплошь и рядом порождают log-события. (Но чаще речь об уровнях TRACE/DEBUG/INFO). Писать или не писать их в лог решает пользователь.

Comment: Сделайте настраиваемую опцию при вызове библиотеки - логировать или нет. Логировать полезно так то вообще. Но лучше, когда опцию можно включить по желанию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исключения и логи и имеют ряд отличий. Логи испольуются не только в случае ошибки. Исключения это часть public interface. Логи могут работать опционально, исключения должны работать всегда. Логи пишутся и читаются разработчиком, они могут содержать внутреннюю информацию. Клиент должен знать, где находятся логи, и отправлять их разработчику, если есть какие-то проблемы.

Должны ли содержать логи информацию об исключениях - это решение разработчика. Лучше это делать, потому что ленивый клиент не всегда правильно обрабатывает исключения.

Если библиотека имеет свои собственные потоки, то единственный способ получить детальную информацию - это лог. Поток не выполняется в контексте пользовательской функции.

И наконец, где держать логи. Библиотека может сама их создавать. Например, под Windows где-нибудь в директории `Users`. Обычно это делается в библиотеках для работы с устройствами.

Другой способ - передавать каждое сообщение для лога клиенту через какой-нибудь callback. Например, через виртуальную функцию. Программа клиента сама решает, что с этим делать. Может записать в файл. Может напечатать в консоли. Этот способ более универсальный.